# Getting error: Uncaught Error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to connect to cloud sql database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm using this code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({ //connection to database
  host: instance_ip,
  port: port,
  user: user,
  password: password,
  database: database
});
```

when trying to connect to a google cloud database and im getting this error: Uncaught Error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

I tried using a socket path instead of an ip address with this format '/cloudsql/cloud_instance_id' but it gave me the error: Uncaught Error Error: connect ENOENT.

The documentation for this is also really confusing and I'm new to this so could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a coding related issue. Either you provided incorrect connection parameters or your routing and security settings are not correct. The latter depends on where your js code is running.